# Kestrel seems to freeze

Tags: asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server, kestrel

I have develop an asp.net-core MVC 3.1 application.

This application is hosted on a Linux server.

This webapp is launched by systemd with this command:

```
/usr/bin/dotnet /pathto/myapp.dll
```

I have an nginx web server which act as a proxy:
Here is my nginx site configuration:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
    ...
}
```

Here is a description of my problem:

- The application is very slow on the first page (about 30-40 seconds. I have a very basic sql server command on this page).
- Then the application respond quickly (1 second).
- I can go back on the previous page, the application respond quickly
- I wait about 2 hours
- The first page is slow again.

I am wondering something: Is it possible kestrel deletes at some interval compiled cache or something like that ? And when a user hits again the first page, kestrel compile something on the fly ?

This is strange because my app is stilled compiled (dlls)

Thanks